# AWS private S3 bucket available from authenticated URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

I am currently using pre signed URL/cookies in a private bucket in order to deliverer an access URL to a specific user from the front app.

From the front, the user clicks on a button that makes an API call to API Gateway + lambda to generate the file (or not if already exists) and then generates a valid pre signed URL for 60 seconds.

I would like to do the same thing : giving a secured URL access to a file in a private bucket BUT without expiration delay because the receiver is no longer a user but an ERP. The filename never changes, only the data in it, and each file can be download from only one ERP.

Is it possible with S3 ?

Comment: Just to clarify... You are wanting a "secret" link that gives access to the file, and anyone who has that link can access the file, with no time restrictions -- is that correct? Would you ever want to be able to block that link in future (eg turn it on & off, but leave the data in-place)?

Comment: Why not use Custom Headers with CloudFront+Lambda@Edge ? Make the URL accessible with a particular header for ERP ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this purely with S3, signed URLs must have a fixed expiry date. This can only extend as far as [7 days](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) away.

If you want to implement this you will need to have a custom application perform this action.

You can set a longer expiry if you use CloudFront through the [DateLessThan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html) condition allowing you to set far in the future.

Alternatively you could create your own signed secret that your store in a DynamoDB table, with an API Gateway application triggering a Lambda to both validate the signed URL and if valid return the cody contents of your S3.